# System does not prompt me for password when login in

Tags: login, password

When login into the system it does not prompt me for a password after putting in my username.
I am able to ssh into the system, when I ssh into the system from another device and I try to sudo -i while im ssh, I get inncorrect password 3 times without ever typing my password.

Comment: Given we currently have not been told the OS/product/release, we can only guess at what you are using & thus not currently help.  What Ubuntu product & release are you using?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting